# How to automatically add hyphen on the state textbox when onchange handler detect on length 4 using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have module where I need to format the value of textbox to xxxx-xxxxxxx. Now I already detect the length of my textbox via using `e.target.value.length` my goal is when the handler detect the length of 4 the hyphen will automatically join after the 3rd length value of textbox. Ex. xxxx- I currently using react js.

**Problem:** the hyphen is inserting in the 4 length.

**Goal:** xxxx-xxxxxxx.

Here is my handler:

```
 handleChange = (e) => {
    
    let val = e.target.id ? e.target.id : e.target.name
    
    var value = { [val]: e.target.value };

    if(val == 'mobile_number') {
      if(e.target.value.length === 4) {
        value = this.state.formData.mobile_number += "-"
      }
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      formData: {
        ...prevState.formData,
        ...value,
      },
    }));
    
  };
```

Here is my mobile_number textbox:

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-control r-5"
  id="mobile_number"
  value={mobile_number || ''}
  required
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  maxLength='12'
/>
```

My Work:

[image: Sample]

Comment: If you rewrite `if(e.target.value.length === 4) {
        value = this.state.formData.mobile_number += "-"
      }` to `if(e.target.value.length === 5) {
        value = this.state.formData.mobile_number += "-"
      }`does it solve it?

Comment: @BudaÖrs yes it works already. however when i do backspacing removing my value. it stops xxxx-x i can't remove all the value.

Comment: Do you want me to give an answer? Or did you already find another solution?

Comment: @BudaÖrs not resolve yet. the problem now is when i backspacing remove the value. it stocks in 5 length i can't remove all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use value from `event.target` instead of using your state, while appending the hyphen. That is because your state has the 'not-still-updated' value which arrives from the handler via event.

Instead

```
      if(e.target.value.length === 4) {
        value = this.state.formData.mobile_number += "-"
      }
```

You should do something like, to support both cases when adding inputs and when deleting inputs:

```
      let value;
      if (
        event.target.value.length === 5 &&
        event.target.value.includes("-")
      ) {
        value = event.target.value.replace("-", "");
      }
      if (event.target.value.length === 4) {
        value = event.target.value + "-";
      }
    }}
```

Edit: link to sandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/add-hyphen-after-4-input-pxohf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: value = e.target.value + "-"; this won't work because formData has many properties.

Comment: RIght, i added sandbox with working example. It is not same class component, but idea remains same

Comment: It works on component base. Just it is functional component and your code is written with class component. You need to incorporate the code i paste in your onChange handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
let input = "78945612378584"
let firstFour = input.substring(0,4)
let last =  input.substring(4,input.length)
let d = firstFour+'-'+last
console.log(d) //"7894-5612378584"
```